# What IPv6 formats can the fefe.de patches to DJBDNS accept?

Tags: ipv6, tinydns, djbdns

I'm using a web server that uploads its DNS entries to a TinyDNS server for name resolution. I'd like to be able to put in some AAAA records, but I've no idea what format TinyDNS is expecting them in - the field delimiter is `:` so I have a feeling that putting in something like `::1` would cause it not to work.

I'm assuming the IPv6 support is from [www.fefe.de/dns](http://www.fefe.de/dns). Anyone know what that takes?

Comment: You need to figure out if you're patched or not. Then the solution is easily found on the wider internet.

Comment: The DNS is not running on my server, I just send TinyDNS files to another machine that I have no other access to. I've asked them what's running but no response yet. And if it is those patches, I've not been able to find any definitive information on what format they're looking for.

Comment: Have you tried with `[` `]` around the IP address?

Answer (score 1):

The format is the full 128 bits address in hex without any delimiter. For example for `2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334` it's `20010db885a3000000008a2e03707334`.

You can convert an address with http://ipv6-literal.com/ by taking the "IPv6 longest" and removing the separators.

Source: I added the record with the `add-host6` script.